# How should I declared data in Java that was captured from communication with USB?

Tags: java, jssc

I'm using the [jSSC](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector) library to set up a connection via USB port. I used a Windows application Device Monitoring Studio to capture what a certain Windows program sends to a device. Here's screenshot of captured data:

[image]

**Here's my question:** how should I declare the data above in Java?
Should it be i.e. an array of `bytes`:

```
byte[] bytesToSend = {0x10, 0x00, 0x0b, ....
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Sounds about right to have byte data in a byte array.  Would probably read it from a file when it's more than a few bytes.